# sIFR - getting a:hover to work in navigation list

Tags: sifr, hover

I am currently struggling with sIFR and a:hover.
My problem site is hosted at http://irene.huditsch.info

I have the following HTML code:

```
 <body id="irene-huditsch-info">
      <div id="header">
    <h1>Irene Huditsch</h1>
    <div id="top-nav">
       <ul>
          <li id="impressum">
        <a href="impressum.html" rel="index">Impressum</a>
          </li>
          <li id="kontakt">
        <a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
          </li>
       </ul>    
    </div>
        ...
```

My sIFR-config.js looks like:

```
sIFR.replace(braganza, {
  selector: 'div#top-nav a',
  css: '.sIFR-root { background-color: transparent; color: #FFFFFF; line-height: 13px; font-size: 11px; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer; } .sIFR-root:hover { color: #592b02; }',
  wmode: 'transparent'
});
```

But the hover doesn't take effect. I tried different solution with no success either.

When I write

```
sIFR.replace(braganza, {
  selector: 'div#top-nav li',
  css: 'a { background-color: transparent; color: #FFFFFF; line-height: 13px; font-size: 11px; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer; } a:hover { color: #592b02; }',
  wmode: 'transparent'
});
```

(which seems logical to me), the list items are not rendered at all.

Could you please give me an advice how to do it correctly with the structure given?

Thanks,
Roman

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the `a` directly will not work, since the Flash movie will only contain the link text and not the link itself.

Your second example should work, assuming you've removed the first attempt, however I see that on the page you're using `.sIFR-root a` as the CSS selector. That might be confusing Flash a little. Also, the `background-color`, `line-height` and `cursor` properties are not supported for `a` elements.